# Java Beginner Having Trouble Using Integer.parseInt for Converting a String into an integer

Tags: java

I am creating a batch program that reads an external input file that contains

credit card numbers and then sums the digits(from right to left), starting at the

last digit and skipping every other digit. I have to treat the input as a String and not

numeric. My code looks like:

```
          int oddSum = 0, digit = 0;
            for(int odd = (cardNumber.length() - 1); odd >= 0; odd = odd - 2)
            {
                digit = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber);
                oddSum += digit;
            }
```

But String cardNumber is the whole String, while I just need the single digit. Say:

```
            cardNumber = "4388576018402626";
```

How can I get, let's say "6", turned into an integer?

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to parse anything if you only need to treat one digit at a time :

```
String cardNumber = "4388576018402626";
int d = cardNumber.charAt(0) - '0';  // = 4
```

But if you insist on using `Integer.parseInt()`, use the String.[substring(begin, end)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) method :

```
int d = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(0, 1));  // = 4
```

** **UPDATE** **

Or perhaps this even better solution :

```
char[] chars = cardNumber.toCharArray();
int oddSum = 0, digit = 0, len = chars.length - 1;
for(int odd = len; odd >= 0; odd -= 2)
{
    if (Character.isDigit(chars[odd])) {
       digit = Character.getNumericValue(chars[odd]);
       oddSum += digit;
    } //else {
      // do something... throw an exception, whatever here 
    //}
}
```

Comment: There is some value to sticking with `parseInt`.  If `cardNumber` happens to contain something besides decimal digits, `parseInt` will throw an exception, while the above character encoding hack will just silently produce junk.

Comment: @rlibby, I'm not too fund of using try..catch blocks in simple validation if possible. For example, using charAt(i) - '0' should produce a value between 0 and 9; any other value should be considered as an invalid input character. No need to throw an exception for that. Plus, the charAt() method is faster than using substring() and parseInt() ... or worst! using pasreInt(Stirng.valueOf(char)) !!

Comment: @Yanick Rochon, the exception `parseInt` throws in unchecked (`java.lang.NumberFormatException`), and, yes, there is a speed-safety trade off.

Comment: @rlibby, I still don't see any benefit in Integer.parseInt() (see update)

Comment: @Yanick Rochon, your update still just fails silently.  If `cardNumber` is `"juicy mangoes"` then your update yields `0` for `oddSum`.  This is fine if you have already validated the input, but obviously bogus if not.  On the other hand you could just let `parseInt` do the validating.

Comment: @rlibby, unless this method is to check whether the string is or is not a valid card number, this validation should not be treated there. But in any case, you can throw your exception in the else block still... even better! you can throw your own InvalidCardNumberException if you want!

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get, let's say "6", turned into an integer?

```
Integer.parseInt("6");
```

> But String cardNumber is the whole String, while I just need the single digit.

So then just get a single digit:

```
String cardNumber = "4388576018402626";
String digit = cardNumber.substring(i, i + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate through the string as if it were an array of individual characters; use `cardNumber.toCharArray()`.

```
int oddSum = 0, digit = 0;
char[] cardNumberDigits = cardNumber.toCharArray();
for(int odd = cardNumberDigits.length - 1; odd >= 0; odd = odd - 2) {
    digit = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(cardNumberDigits[odd]));
    oddSum += digit;
}
```

Comment: But then how do I get the char from the array turned into an integer?

Comment: Use `String.valueOf` or `Character.toString` to convert the char to a String and then use `Integer.parseInt`. The key is to make your code read cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

The charAt() accessor method allows you to get a single character at an index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab a substring of cardNumber

```
String cardNumber = "4388576018402626";
int start = cardNumber.length()-2;
int end = cardNumber.length()-1;
String subString = cardNumber.substring(start, end);
int numberSix = Integer.parseInt(subString);
```